# open a notebook in azure machine learning studio

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-machine-learning-service

I am new to Azure machine learning.

I am trying to open a notebook from my datasets in azure machine learning studio classic.

but i get this error :

Opening notebook failed. Notebook id: ebb913d436ef45d4b1872b6e5d7167dc.

as you can see on the picture i don't even have the possibility to access all my notebooks in the left menu.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Azure ML Studio (Classic) notebooks feature has retired, however, the new Azure ML Studio supports [Jupyter Notebooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-run-jupyter-notebooks) in your workspace.

Before the retirement, a banner was available on the portal to download your notebooks and data:

> The notebooks(preview) feature will be shut down at 4/13/2020. After
> shut down the notebooks tab will disappear and the notebooks data can
> not be restored. Please download your notebooks data before 4/13/2020.
> Click here to check how to download your data. If you have further
> question, contact us

Hence, the notebook is no longer available if it wasn't saved by the deadline.